# What is the fastest way to check if something exist in a vector in Rust?

Tags: python, vector, serialization, rust, pickle

I have a large list of data in a text file. I read the text file and added each line to a vector, but when I check if some string exists in that vector using contain method, the app slows down. I saw the same kine of functionality in python with pickle which it was really fast. How can make checking if something exist in a vector faster?

Comment: So, how does it *python* or *pickle* related?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Because I want to replicate the same thing in Rust.

Comment: "How can make checking if something exists in a vector faster?". Are you running in release mode? That's often one of the main issues when someone finds something to be slow in rust compared to language XYZ.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Yeah, of course I built it using release mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented binary search and it got really fast. It's kinda too good to be true.

```
fn main() {

    let mut  v: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    v.push("afd".to_string());
    v.push("zdgdg".to_string());
    v.push("bvbvb".to_string());

    v.sort_unstable();

    println!("{:?}", v);
    match v.binary_search(&"bvbvb".to_string()) {
        Ok(u) => {
            println!("yes {}", u)
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("No {}", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No `binary_search` in Vec in fact?

Comment: Why would it be "too good to be true"? The entire point of binary search is to work in logarithmic time, which is completely logically much faster than linear search (as array size growss, for a 3-array it's probably slower but I'll assume the real case is much larger).

Comment: @Masklinn I also did the same thing in Kotlin. The speed is unbelievable.

Answer (score 4):

In order for `.contains()` to find an element in the Vec, it must traverse each element and compare the element to the search string to check if it's there.  The easiest optimization you can make is to use a HashMap instead, where the key is the string you want to search for, and the value can be `()` since it's not important.  You can then search for a given string with `.get()` and either get `Some(())` if it's contained in the map or `None` otherwise.  It's possible to iterate over all elements of a hashmap, so you can still retrieve all the stored values, but you'll gain a much faster ability to search

Comment: Better than `HashMap` with `()` as key is to use the also available `HashSet`.